# Torque lesson in Physics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, magnetic-fields, torque

For the force on a current-carrying wire, Torque,  was derived using the assumption that the cross-section area of the wire is constant along its length. Is this equation still valid if the cross-section area varies along the wire’s length? Why or why not?

Comment: Showing the actual derivation would be a big help.

Comment: You have to calculate the torsional constants of segments of the wire and combine them as in [springs in series](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/313992/85443).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magnetic force on a current-carrying wire is equal to $ILB \sin(\theta)$, where I = current, L = length of wire in the magnetic field, B = magnetic field, and $\theta$ is the angle the wire makes with the magnetic field.

There is no cross-sectional area involved. Even if there is a varying cross-sectional area, the current in a single wire is a constant due to the current continuity equation.